# How can I find out which users have uttered a certain keyword most often in chat?

Tags: support, chat-transcript, chat-search

I'd like to find fellow SE users who are most inclined to chat about a certain topic. For example, we can find out that this user said "Meteor" 35 times:

https://chat.stackoverflow.com/search?q=Meteor&user=3961546

How can I find the top users in chat (by simple frequency) for a given keyword?

Comment: You can't. You'll need to scrape the chat transscript.

Comment: @rene Or rather, scrape the search result pages for "Meteor" not restricted by user, grabbing user names.

Comment: Either way scraping is needed....

Comment: This would become trivial if and when [chat will be included in SEDE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/198260/why-is-chat-stackexchange-com-not-exposed-in-data-explorer)

Comment: @ShadowWizard in 6-8 generations...

Comment: @rene well, it's not declined so there's still hope :)

Answer (score 5):

Though it's answered in comments, this deserves a proper answer.

This can't be done with the tools Stack Exchange gives. Chat messages can't be sorted this way by user given the default search tools, so you'd need to improvise a scraping tool.