# Stack Exchange Data Explorer and Stack Exchange Data Dumps should include public chat room messages

Tags: feature-request, chat, data-explorer, data-dump

All data from public chat rooms should be available in the data dumps and queryable in the Stack Exchange Data Explorer. Of course, deleted messages should not be available (since the general public doesn't have the ability to view contents of deleted chat messages). Mod only and any other private / non-public chat rooms should also not be indexed, for obvious reasons.

---

I am aware of [Why is chat.stackexchange.com not exposed in Data Explorer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/198260/622284), which asks why the data is not there. **This is a request for that data to be there**. If there was an answer from staff, then perhaps a rationale for not including it could be seen as an implicit way to decline this request to include it. Until staff either explain why the data is not available or explicitly decline this feature request, I don't see why this should be closed as a duplicate of that question.

Comment: And why would that be needed?

Comment: @rene For completeness of the data access? To allow people to make interesting queries? To provide off-line access to all SE data (chat is part of SE data)? I think including it in SEDE would be the most interesting to people. There are some interesting queries - I'd like to see what people can do if they also include chat data.

Comment: I can imagine all that but for SEDE you can argue that having that data helps the community to detect trends, to find relations between posts, to find dubious content, all to improve on the goal and vision of the SE network, to have a collection of (high) quality questions and answers. I'm not sure how having access to chat data in SEDE is helping improving post quality.  If there are interesting queries you have in your mind, can you share those?

Comment: @rene I don't have anything in mind now. But I don't see how that really matters. I'm asking for this data to be included so that users who have interesting ideas can make queries, and maybe those queries can be used to find information that turns into other feature requests or discussions.

Comment: Data liberation should be a reflex, not something to fight for…

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is chat.stackexchange.com not exposed in Data Explorer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/198260/why-is-chat-stackexchange-com-not-exposed-in-data-explorer) (yes, I know it's phrased as a question, but it's tagged [tag:feature-request]).

Comment: There's [Why is chat.stackexchange.com not exposed in Data Explorer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/198260/282094) where it's answered, and [Is there a data dump for SE chat logs?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/366864/282094)

Comment: @starball No. There is no answer from staff as to why chat data is not exposed in Data Explorer or data dumps. If there was, then perhaps that could be an implicit declined request, depending on what that answer is. However, this feature request is still valid: I believe that this data should be exposed via the explorer and dumps.

Comment: The dupe is asking the same thing. Having a [tag:feature-request] tag is proof it's actually asking to have that feature, the title is not relevant.

Comment: @ShadowTheKidWizard That question is not phrased as a request for it to be added, but as a question asking why it's not there. The fact that the tags don't correspond to the actual text of the question doesn't change the actual characteristic of the question (as a question, not a request). As such, I've voted to reopen and have retagged the other one so its tags match its text.