# Is there a data dump for SE chat logs?

Tags: feature-request, support, chat, data-explorer, data-dump

I am working on a research project looking at Stackexchange posts. I am aware of the data explorer as well as the data dump stored on the internet archive. I was wondering if there was any information about the chat logs (i.e. if those are considered publicly available in the same way that posts/comments are).

I see this [post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239347/adding-chat-transcripts-as-an-available-data-dump) (which is similar, but six years old so possibly out of date?)

I also see [these](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129374/obtaining-full-chat-transcripts) [posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135727/crawling-stack-overflow-instead-of-the-dumps-for-fresher-data-in-our-search-resu) talking about different ways to build a web crawler in a way that would be minimally disruptive for the site.

Is there anything more up to date that I am missing?

Comment: Chat hasn't really changed in 6 years, so, i'd say that post is still pretty much where things are

Comment: Are you asking *whether* there is such a data dump ([tag:support]), or *for* there to be such a data dump ([tag:feature-request])?